# データフレームの2列から辞書を作る際、keyが重複しているのでvalueをリスト化する方法

Tags: python, pandas

データフレームから
`dic1 = dict(zip(df['pid'], df['nid']))`
を使って辞書を作りたいのですが、
pidに重複があるためうまくいきません。（おそらく上書きが起こっています。）
(pid, nid) = {'8':'11', '8':'19'}
の際はkeyが重複していればvalueがリストになるように、
この場合だと{8:[11,19]}
のようにしたいです。
(pid, nid) = {'32':'131', '32':'192', '32':'1962'}
の場合だと{32:[131,192,1962]}
でしょうか。

**追記**
例としてデータフレームを作成しました。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame({'pid': ['8', '8', '1', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '3'],
              'col_1': np.arange(3, 12),
              'nid': ('11', '19', '8', '354', '5', '64', '432', '142', '2')})
```

**再追記**
metropolisさんの方法に補足です。
`df.groupby('pid').nid.apply(lambda x: x.to_list()).to_dict()`
とすると要素一つのものもリストになるようです。

Comment: こんな記事 [kemsakurai/Note.md](https://gist.github.com/kemsakurai/3f2c5ad0638391e01fd687bd5fa8bd88) があって参照先はこちらのようです。[Merge dictionaries retaining values for duplicate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24745181/9014308)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。その記事は自分も見つけましたが、2つのデータフレームをくっつけてキーが重複するもの、だったのでこの質問で求めているものとは違うと感じました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` でまとめて `apply` で形式を整えます。

```py
>>> df.groupby('pid').nid.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if len(x)==1 else x.to_list()).to_dict()
{'1': '8', '3': '2', '32': ['354', '5', '64', '432', '142'], '8': ['11', '19']}
```